Using puppeteer on a webpage
Basically I want to use the puppeteer output in the html file. Here is my code:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const scrape = async (site, value) => {
var uSite = "https://www.cosmetica.com.tr/arama/hizliErisim.aspx?tip=U&lang=tr-TR&srt=&text=";
var elWay = "#ctl00_u30_ascArama_urun_ascUrunList_rptDestUrun_ctl00_pnlNormal";
var elDiscountWay = "#ctl00_u30_ascArama_urun_ascUrunList_rptDestUrun_ctl00_pnlIndirim";
switch (site) {
    case "Cosmetica":
        uSite = "https://www.cosmetica.com.tr/arama/hizliErisim.aspx?tip=U&lang=tr-TR&srt=&text=";
        elWay = "#ctl00_u30_ascArama_urun_ascUrunList_rptDestUrun_ctl00_pnlNormal";
        elDiscountWay = "#ctl00_u30_ascArama_urun_ascUrunList_rptDestUrun_ctl00_pnlIndirim";
        break;
    case "Gratis":
        uSite = "https://www.gratis.com/search/";
        elWay = "div.price.ng-star-inserted > div";
        elDiscountWay = "div.price-w-card.ng-star-inserted > div";
    case "Watsons":
        uSite = "https://www.watsons.com.tr/search?searchType=manual&text=";
        elWay = "#products-content-list > e2-content-list > v-root > div > div > v-slot > v-slot-assigned-content > div > div > e2-impression-tracker > div > div.product-tile__details-and-price > div.product-tile__price > div > div > e2-price-badge > div";
        elDiscountWay = "#products-content-list > e2-content-list > v-root > div > div > v-slot > v-slot-assigned-content > div > div > e2-impression-tracker > div > div.product-tile__details-and-price > div.product-tile__price > div > div > div > div > e2-price-badge > div";
    case "Rossmann":
        uSite = "https://www.rossmann.com.tr/catalogsearch/result/?q=";
        elWay = "#eln-product-products > div > ol > li:nth-child(1) > div.product-item-info > div > div.price-box.price-final_price > span > span > p > span.price.desktopPrice";
        elDiscountWay = "#eln-product-products > div > ol > li:nth-child(1) > div.product-item-info > div > div.price-box.price-final_price > span > div > span.price";
    default:
        break;
}

const url = `${uSite}${value}`;

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    executablePath: './chrome/win64-116.0.5793.0/chrome-win64/chrome.exe'
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);

const element = await page.$(elWay);
const dElement = await page.$(elDiscountWay);

if (element || dElement) {
    const text = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, element);
    const dText = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, dElement);
    console.log(`${site}: ${text} | İndirimli: ${dText}`);
} else {
    console.log("err");
}

browser.close();
}

scrape("Cosmetica", 8697432090277);
scrape("Gratis", 8697432090277);
scrape("Watsons", 8697432090277);
scrape("Rossmann", 8697432090277);

It works on the console, as it should, but I can't find a way to work it on the html server. I tried searching on this site, AIs, youtube etc. but i can't find anything that solves this. Can anyone help?

Does this answer your question? How to run Puppeteer code in any web browser?. The normal approach is to host a server and provide an API interface for your browser clients.

No I went to these pages but i can't find a way to solve this. It just gave more errors.

What errors did you get specifically? If you read the links, you basically can't run Node code in a web browser, so if you're trying to do that, then that's why there are errors.
